# Смена цвета фона кнопки и еще одного блока при наведении на кнопку

Tags: jquery, css, hover

Есть блок заголовка с классом `.titlePrice` и кнопка `.buyN`. У обоих одинаковый цвет фона. И нужно чтобы при наведении на кнопку (`hover`) менялся цвет фона и у кнопки, и у блока одновременно. Состряпал такой код. Но он меняет фон только у самой кнопки, у блока `.titlePrice` ничего не меняется.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.buyN').hover(function() {
        $(this).css({'backgroundColor' : '#475bf1'});
        $('titlePrice').css({'backgroundColor' : '#475bf1'});
    })
    $('.buyN').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css({'backgroundColor' : '#5b6ceb'});
        $('titlePrice').css({'backgroundColor' : '#5b6ceb'});
    })
})
```

Comment: Вы указали неправильный селектор, вы забыли точку перед именем класса. Должно быть `.titlePrice`

Comment: Понял, спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий код, я использовал `id` вместо `class`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buyN').hover(function() {
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#475bf1'});
        $('#titlePrice').css({'background-color' : '#475bf1'});
    })
    $('#buyN').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#5b6ceb'});
        $('#titlePrice').css({'background-color' : '#5b6ceb'});
    })
})
```

```css
#titlePrice {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #5b6ceb;
  display: inline-blox;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

#buyN {
  background-color: #5b6ceb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="titlePrice">
  <button id="buyN" >Hello</button>
</div>
```